# JDBC working with Oracle RECORD, TABLE and OBJECT types

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, callable-statement, oracle-objects

How to retrieve Oracle Collection Types in Jdbc. I searched a lot but not found any answer. Below is my stored procedure working fine :

```
create or replace PACKAGE SHOW_SUP AS
  TYPE SUP_COF_REC IS RECORD (
    SUPPLIER_NAME VARCHAR2(32),
    COFFEE_NAME VARCHAR(32)
  );
TYPE_RECORD SUP_COF_REC;
TYPE SUP_COF_TAB IS TABLE OF TYPE_RECORD%TYPE;
PROCEDURE SHOW_SUPPLIERS (SUP_COF_DET OUT SUP_COF_TAB);
END SHOW_SUP;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY SHOW_SUP AS
PROCEDURE SHOW_SUPPLIERS (SUP_COF_DET OUT SUP_COF_TAB) AS
 STR VARCHAR2(2000);
 BEGIN
  STR:='SELECT SUP_NAME, COF_NAME FROM SUPPLIERS S, COFFEES C WHERE
        S.SUP_ID=C.SUP_ID ORDER BY SUP_NAME';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(STR) BULK COLLECT INTO SUP_COF_DET;
 END SHOW_SUPPLIERS;
END SHOW_SUP;
```

Below is the Java Code to run stored proc:

```
String sql="{call SHOW_SUP.SHOW_SUPPLIERS(?)}";
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(sql);
cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY, "SUP_COF_TAB"); //LINE 3
//cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY, "SHOW_SUP.SUP_COF_TAB"); //LINE 4
cs.execute();
```

Error I am receiving at LINE 3/4:

```
SQLException : invalid name pattern: SCOTT.SUP_COF_TAB
java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: SCOTT.SUP_COF_TAB
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata(OracleTypeADT.java:543)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.init(OracleTypeADT.java:462)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.initPickler(ArrayDescriptor.java:1678)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.<init>(ArrayDescriptor.java:291)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:206)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:175)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:158)
    at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:125)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NamedTypeAccessor.otypeFromName(NamedTypeAccessor.java:84)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.TypeAccessor.initMetadata(TypeAccessor.java:89)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.allocateAccessor(T4CCallableStatement.java:629)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameterInternal(OracleCallableStatement.java:166)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatement.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.registerOutParameter(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:1584)
    at com.jdbc.callstatement.CallableStatementSample.main(CallableStatementSample.java:48)
```

I also tried to run a new stored procedure *without RECORD Type* but same error exists:

```
create or replace PACKAGE SHOW_COF AS
TYPE COF_TAB IS TABLE OF COFFEES%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
PROCEDURE SHOW_COFFEES (COF_DET OUT COF_TAB);
END SHOW_COF;
```

I somewhere found that Array descriptor or struct descriptor can be used but how to used it in registerOutParameter, not any doc/site has explain. I got stuck here.

Comment: What's your database and the jdbc driver versions?

Comment: Fetching the Metadata gives the following: _Driver Name_ : Oracle JDBC driver, _Driver Version_ : 11.1.0.7.0-Production, _DB Name_ : Oracle, _DB Version_ : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Answer (score 1):

Use the fully-qualified name of the SQL structured type, as below:

`cs.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.ARRAY, "SHOW_SUP.SUP_COF_TAB"); //LINE 3.`

To read the out parameter, do as the following in your java code:

```
// Get the out parameter as java.sql.Array
java.sql.Array ntab = (java.sql.Array) cStmt.getObject(1);

// Now get the rows from the nested table
Object[] rows = (Object[])ntab.getArray();

// For each row
for (Object row: rows) {
    // Get the columns
    Object[] cols = ((Struct) row).getAttributes();

    String supplierName = cols[0].toString();
    String coffeeName = cols[1].toString();
}
```

Comment: As already tried before posting. Go through my Java code Line4 which is commented. The only thing that will change is exception first two line. It will print as {SQLException : invalid name pattern: SHOW_SUP.SUP_COF_TAB
java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: SHOW_SUP.SUP_COF_TAB}

Comment: Is your Oracle database older than 12c? The types are supposed to work from 12c.

Comment: Yes. Fetching the Metadata gives the following: _Driver Name_ : Oracle JDBC driver, _Driver Version_ : 11.1.0.7.0-Production,  _DB Name_: Oracle,  _DB Version_ : Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Comment: Ok. For older database you may use setPlsqlIndexTable() API as advised in the following link: 
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2946758026631

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can work only with sql level object in jdbc (UDT, collections ). But in your case you can consider using sys_refcursors. 
In java sys_refcursor is represented by ordinary resultset.

Concept below:

ORACE:

```
 PROCEDURE SHOW_SUPPLIERS (SUP_COF_DET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
..

    PROCEDURE SHOW_SUPPLIERS (SUP_COF_DET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
     c_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR
     BEGIN
      open c_cursor  for 'SELECT SUP_NAME, COF_NAME FROM SUPPLIERS S, COFFEES C WHERE
            S.SUP_ID=C.SUP_ID ORDER BY SUP_NAME';
      SUP_COF_DET := c_cursor 
     END SHOW_SUPPLIERS;
```

Java:

```
String sql="{call SHOW_SUP.SHOW_SUPPLIERS(?)}";
CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall(sql);
cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
cs.executeUpdate();
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(1);
```